# Simple ResourceManager example not working inside unit test

Tags: c#, globalization, vs-unit-testing-framework

Trying to follow this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht.aspx The problem with the example is it's a mixture of instructions for visual studio users and command line users, but I have done my best to follow only the VS instructions.

So I have: Created a new Unit Test Project in visual studio called `Example`.

I added a resource called `Greeting.en-US.resx` and put a string in called `HelloString`.

**Edit** I have now added another default resource file called `Greeting.resx` string is "Hello (Default)"

[image]

My unit test:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Resources;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Example
{
    [TestClass]
    public class GreetingTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Hello()
        {
            var newCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;

            var rm = new ResourceManager("Example.Greeting",
                                         typeof (GreetingTests).Assembly);
            Assert.AreEqual("Hello (US)", rm.GetString("HelloString"));
        }
    }
}
```

Now it only ever loads the default

`Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<Hello (US)>. Actual:<Hello (Default)>.`

The same code works in a Console App just fine.

Comment: Your resource file name is Greetings (plural), but you are requesting resource in singular form - Greeting. Although I'm surprised that your code works in console. May be you've made an typo in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think this happens because your unit testing tool shadow copies main assembly but does not copy the satellite one. [Enable shadow copying for satellite assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413832/how-do-i-turn-off-shadow-copy-in-a-visual-studio-2010-test-project) and rerun the unit test.

To confirm my guess check value of Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location against .Codebase.

Comment: Ah, I didn't spot there were shadow assemblies being created.